# Validate the format of a string of comma separated words with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, format

I'm trying to validate a string of comma separated words from a text field in a ruby class using regex. The following should be valid:

```
word

word, word, word

word,word,word
```

And the following should be invalid:

```
word word word
```

I thought this would work

```
/([a-z]+){1}(,\s*[a-z]+)*/i
```

On Rubular, it seems to be valid, but when I validate in my class as follows, it accepts what should be invalid strings.

```
@tag_regex = /([a-z]+){1}(,\s*[a-z]+)*/i

validates :tags, 
:allow_blank => true,
:format => { :with => @tag_regex, :message => "Invalid tag format." }
```

I'm not sure whether my problem lies in the regex or with the method of validation itself. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to use `^`(start of the string) and `$`(end of the string)

So,it should be

```
/^([a-z]+)(,\s*[a-z]+)*$/i
```

---

Without `^`,`$` it would match anywhere in between the string..With `^`,`$` you are making it match **exactly**

Comment: Yes, and you don't need the `{1}` as it's the default.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your super fast response. Will mark as correct when it lets me in about 7 mins :)